# PHP Webscraping to JSON

Tags: php, json, web-scraping

I am currently webscraping information from a service that doesnt provide json. The goal is to take the code from below (small fraction) and just grab the items that are currently importing. Then produce a json array in php.

So for example I want from the first entry

House M.D. (Season 4) (Episodes 1 - 5)
0-S_419212
Theater
DVD
Jun. 02, 6:05 pm
In progress, 14 minutes left

The next entry isn't an state='active' so skip it.

Example Code

```
<tr class="import_row" handle="3f0761be271334a-L1_257" selection_handle="0-S_419212" state="active" utcstart="1464912324">
    <td valign="top" class="start_time" nowrap="">Jun. 02,  6:05 pm</td> 
    <td valign="top" class="title">House M.D. (Season 4) (Episodes 1 - 5)</td>
    <td valign="top" class="reader">Theater</td>
    <td valign="top" class="type">DVD</td>
    <td valign="top" class="status">In progress, 14 minutes left</td>
    <td valign="top" class="edit"></td>
</tr>


<tr class="import_row" handle="3f0761be271334a-L1_255" selection_handle="0-S_4c6be1" state="completed" utcstart="1464673067">
    <td valign="top" class="start_time" nowrap="">May. 30, 11:37 pm</td> 
    <td valign="top" class="title"><a href="javascript:getDetails('0-S_4c6be1');">National Treasure 2: Book of Secrets (Feature)</a></td>
    <td valign="top" class="reader">Theater</td>
    <td valign="top" class="type">DVD</td>
    <td valign="top" class="status">Completed in 26 minutes</td>
    <td valign="top" class="edit"></td>
</tr>
```

Also this is the code I use to get the info into PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://10.1.1.150/home/index.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
$cookie_file = "cookie.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$input_lines = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: You might find the DOMdocument class helpful for parsing results http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Im not looking for something to read about. I need a solution.